# transfer javascript var into html form textbox

Tags: javascript, events, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

Hi i have click event that will pop up a info window & marker each time a click is detected on the map.

In the infowindow, i am trying to display the lat and lng as soon as the click is completed. i manage to get the event.latlng, but how to transfer the location.lat(), or location.lng() into the html text box?

Thanks

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) { 
placeMarker(event.latLng);
 });
```

```
 function placeMarker(location) {
```

`var html = "Add a reminder:" +
                "<form id='remindForm' onsubmit='return false;' />" +
                "Latitude:     <INPUT id='test' TYPE='TEXT' NAME='lat' VALUE='' SIZE='25' MAXLENGTH='50' disabled='disabled'><br />" +
                "Longtitude:   <INPUT TYPE='TEXT' NAME='lng' VALUE='' SIZE='25' MAXLENGTH='50' disabled='disabled'><br />" +
                "<textarea id='remindBox' style='width: 250px; height: 40px'></textarea><br />" +
                "<input type='button' value='Submit' onclick='submitBlog()'></form>";

          if ( remindMarker ) {
            remindMarker.setPosition(location);
          } else {
            remindMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: location,
              map: map
            });
          }

           infoWindow.setContent(html);
           infoWindow.open(map, remindMarker);
           document.getElementById(test).value=location.lat();
        }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById('test').value=location.lat();`

test is not a variable, it is a string.